# How to use friend with compojure?

Tags: authentication, clojure, compojure

I'm fairly new to clojure, and I'm trying to add an authentication system to a compujure app and for that I'm using cemerick.friend.

All the routes are working fine, but I'm never able to login, even when using a dummy in memory database (if you can call it that).

The problem, I believe, is on the `cemerick.friend.credentials/bcrypt-credential-fn`, which is never validating my credentials.

Here's a gist with the relevant code: https://gist.github.com/zamith/5940965

Any help on how to solve this problem would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `workflows/interactive-form` where currently you specify `workflows/interactive-login-redirect`.

The latter function's purpose is to serve as the default `:login-failure-handler`. What it does is perform the redirect after a failed login attempt; it certainly makes no attempt to log a user in.

You also need to remove the `(resp/redirect "/signup")` from the body of the `friend/authenticated` form in your `"/dashboard"` route, as it's unconditionally redirecting logged in users to the signup page. (That the redirect happens is in fact proof of the user being authenticated, since otherwise the body of `friend/authenticated` would not be evaluated and there's nothing else in the code which could cause a redirect to `"/signup"`.)

With these two changes, the app works for me.

Comment: I've tried with `workflows/interactive-form` and it didn't work, that's why I changed it, and then forgot to change it back.

Simply put, I would like to login with username `root` and password `admin_password` and I can't. Any idea why?

Comment: Well, you don't include all the relevant code in the Gist. For one thing, what does your login form look like?

Comment: Ok, the problem was in fact in the handler namespace; missed it while reading earlier. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I've made both the changes, and now when I try to login I get redirect to the home page, whereas I would like it to print "Hello". How can I achieve this?

I've updated the code in the gist.

Comment: Change `:default-landing-uri` to `"/dashboard"` in the options passed to `friend/authenticate`.